# Google Sheets script copying subset of cells on row using onEdit boolean check

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple sheets on a spreadsheet tracking similar data that multiple people have access to. At certain times we hide rows/columns to track a specific value (e.g.: all inventory being sent to X location or what inventory is on Y truck). However doing so means halting everyone else's work so I'm looking to add a new sheet to the spreadsheet that has a subset of the data among all the sheets. We already have a boolean in place that would flag which rows should be relevant for this new sheet. So what I want the script to do is when this boolean is set to TRUE, it would copy that row to the new sheet. However, not all of the data on that row is relevant either, so I'm looking to only copy the needed columns of that row as well. E.g.: when the boolean on row 1921 is set to true, for row 1921 copy columns A,B,C,F,G,I,K,M to the new sheet.

I'm new to javascript and google sheets so I'm struggling.

This is the code I have come up with so far to just try to copy the entire row to the new sheet.

```
function onEdit(e){
    const sh = e.range.getSheet();
    if((sh.getName() == "ScriptTestingSource"/*add OR statements to include other sheets*/) && 
        e.range.columnStart==18 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == "TRUE"){
        let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        let sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("ScriptTestingTarget")

        targetSheet.insertRows(2,1);

        let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
        let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
        let sourceRow = e.range.getRow();

        let sourceColumns = sourceValues[sourceRow].length;
    
        let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2,1,1,sourceColumns);
        targetRange.setValues(sourceValues[sourceRow-1]);
    }
}
```

I believe the issue lies with my targetRange value.

When it comes to copying the specific columns, I figure that I should be able to splice() off the unneeded values from sourceValues, and restrict columns of targetRange to match the length.

Finally, I have concerns using the entire data range and values, as the sheets are rather large so if possible I'd like to only get the relevant range from the source sheet.

EDIT: Updated Code

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if((sh.getName() == "ScriptTestingSource") && 
  e.range.columnStart==18 && e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.value == "TRUE"){
    let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('ScriptTestingTarget')
    targetSheet.insertRows(2,1);
    
    let sourceRow = e.range.getRow();
    let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRow,1,1,11);
    let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

    sourceValues[0].splice(7,1)
    sourceValues[0].splice(3,2)
    sourceValues[0].splice(0,1)
    
    let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2,1,1,7);
    targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);

  }
}
```

I got it working! But now I'm curious, is there a quick way to find the last row?

FINAL EDIT: And it now finds the last row in the target sheet, inserts a new row after, then inserts the data

```
function onEdit(e){
const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if((sh.getName() == "ScriptTestingSource") && 
  e.range.columnStart==18 && e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.value == "TRUE"){
    //get source and target sheets
    let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let targetSheet = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName('ScriptTestingTarget')

    //get row where edit occurs
    let sourceRow = e.range.getRow();
    //get data range of edited row
    let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRow,1,1,11);
    //get values of the edited row
    let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

    //splice off unneeded values
    sourceValues[0].splice(7,1)
    sourceValues[0].splice(3,2)
    sourceValues[0].splice(0,1)

    //insert new row on on target sheet
    let targetRows = targetSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()
    targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetRows,1);
    //get range of target sheet, the newly created row
    let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetRows+1,1,1,7);
    //insert values to new row
    targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should consider change the data format to something like a csv, normalize and than parse it

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation:

Copying subset of cells from a row in the source sheet when checkbox is checked to the destination sheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('source'); 
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('destination'); 
  var range = e.range; 
  var row = e.range.getRow(); 
  var column = e.range.getColumn(); 

  if(row >= 2 && column == 7 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'destination'){
    if(range.getValue() == true){
      var value = sourceSheet.getRange(row,1,1,6).getValues(); 
      value[0].splice(3,1); // you can change the first parameter of splice depends on the column that you want to remove.
      console.log(value); 
      destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,value[0].length).setValues(value); 
    } 
  }
}
```

### Sample input:

[image: sheet data]

### Sample Output:

[image: output]

**Note:** Array indexing starts from [0]. In the sample above, `splice(3,1)` is referring to City column.

Please change the row and column on the first `if` statement depends on your data.

### Reference:

- [splice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)
- [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)